# how can I have hover style by default?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list and each has css for hover state. 
by default every item is black and by hovering turns blue. 
**my problem:** i want the first item to be blue even before hovering by loading the page. once user hovers other item the first one is not blue anymore and is like other normal items which turns blue only by hovering.

here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFq8f/).

html:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul li:hover {
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: what is your default styling? not very sure about your problem but u can try ul:not(:first-child) { ..can u please make your question a little bit more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>

<style>
ul li:hover, ui li.active {
    color:blue;
}
</style>

<script>
$('ul').hover(function(){ $('ul li').removeClass('active'); } , function(){});
</script>
```

Comment: you got my point but your code dose not work. can you fix it here: http://jsfiddle.net/dFq8f/8/

Comment: @PersianMan it still not working as expected in your question, when u hover on last items it the active class does not remove, when u hover on the li.active list then only the active class remove. Check it once.

Comment: You could use [`.one("mouseover", ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) here. There's no need to remove the class over and over again

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply a `:hover` style to something that isn't currently in the hover state. But you can apply the same style to a selected item by using a class:

```
<ul>
    <li class="selected">one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>

ul li:hover, ul li.selected {
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but as i said after hovering the second and third item the first one won't remain blue

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in styling the first `<li>` in the opposite way you could use the `:first-child` pseudo-class:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

```
ul li:first-child,
ul li:hover {
    color: blue;
}

ul li:first-child:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFq8f/10/)

Otherwise, I would suggest following a class-based approach like suggested.